# Using Map function over an array of objects inside React native not working

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, map-function

I have an array of two objects which contains student details. I want to iterate the array using map function to show the name and the 'sub1' of both students in the screen using react native.
My array is this:

```
const Students = [{'id':"123",
              'name':'Rahul',
              'subjects':{
                'sub1': 'math',
                'sub2':'physics'}
              },
              {'id':"345",
              'name':'Maximilian',
              'subjects':{
                'sub1': 'French',
                'sub2': 'English'}
              }]
```

I am writing the map function like below:

```
{Students.map((student:any)=> (
  <View>  
   <Text>
      {student.name},
      {student.subjects.sub1}
   </Text>
  </View>
 ))}
```

I want to see the texts as

> Rahul,math Maximilian,French

in my screen. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to use `<Text>` components

Comment: I edited my question, after adding <Text> it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return(
//display here whatever you want to 
{Students.map((student:any)=> (
  return(<View>  
   <Text>
      {student.name},
      {student.subjects.sub1}
   </Text>
  </View>)
 ))}
)
```